# knockout, too many containerless if statements

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

in my application I am using knockout.
I have a set of questions, and every question has a type, which determines the component in which it will be rendered (questions template, see below).

And my problem is that it renders all the if statements into page. So my page is just full of if statements(which makes the html page grow in size), which are empty.

Html example:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'questions', foreach: questions }">
<!-- ko if: type === "label" -->
<!-- ko template: { name: 'label_component' } -->
<div data-bind="visible: show, css: { root : isRoot }" class="root">
    <div data-bind="html: text, attr: {id: id}" id="1">Question text</div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: type === "bool" --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: type === "multitext" --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: type === "text" --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: type == "number" --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: type === "dropdown" --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: type === "date" --><!-- /ko -->
```

.............

So you can see there is 7 unnecessary if statements rendered for 1 component.

My template:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'questions', foreach: questions }"></div>

<script id="questions" type="html/text">
    <!-- ko if: type === "label" -->
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'label_component' } --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: type === "bool" -->
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'radio_btn_component' } --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: type === "multitext" -->
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'multi_text_component' } --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: type === "text" -->
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'text_component' } --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: type == "number" -->
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'numeric_component' } --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: type === "dropdown" -->
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'dropdown_component' } --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: type === "date" -->
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'date_component' } --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

So my question:
Is there any way around this? Can I get somehow stop rendering those unused if statements into page?

Thank you all for any ideas

Comment: one way could be to create your html in your view model and use something similar to the `html` binding to render the desired template...

Comment: Could you point me to any code example please? I am not exactly sure what you mean by that. @gkb

Comment: take a look at the html binding here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html. You can see how the example binds `viewModel.details` (which contains html markup) to the html using `data-bind="html: details"`. So you can build whatever templates you need to render (based on `type`), assign that markup as a string to an observable and use it in the `html` binding..This however, won't save you from writing `if-else` clauses, but will surely get rid of those container less `if`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks to @gkb, I look at it from different perspective and come up with this solution.

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'questions', foreach: questions }"></div>

<script id="questions" type="html/text">
    <!-- ko template: { name: componentName() } --><!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

And componentName is a function on my view model:

```
question.componentName = function() {

        switch (question.type) {
            case "label":
                return "label_component";
            case "bool":
                return "radio_btn_component";
            case "multitext":
                return "multi_text_component";
            case "text":
                return "text_component";
            case "number":
                return "numeric_component";
            case "dropdown":
                return "dropdown_component";
            case "date":
                return "date_component";
        }
        return "label_component";
    }
```

If you have any other ideas how this could be achieved. Please let me know.

Comment: I've used this approach before - it's fine.  One way to make it even slicker is to name everything "by convention", so you can build the template name directly from `question.type`, so you don't need the `switch` to choose the right template name - if you add further types/components later on, it's one less place to update.  You're almost there already - only `bool`, `multitext` and `number` have a "different" template name.

Comment: glad to see you figured it out..:-)